# Change the color of page control dots in a Three20 TTLauncherView

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, three20, uipagecontrol

I'm using the Three20 library to create a TTLauncherView in an iPhone app that I'm working on. Is there an easy way to change the color of the dots in the page control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TTPageControl uses three20's stylesheets to customize its dots. Here's the relevant part in [TTDefaultStyleSheet](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Style/Sources/TTDefaultStyleSheet.m#L594).